Angular new control flow syntax highlighting and indentation in Visual Studio Code not working
I'm encountering an issue with syntax highlighting and indentation in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) while working with Angular's new control flow syntax. Despite having the appropriate extensions installed (vscode-angular-html-inline) and ensuring that my VSCode settings are configured correctly, the syntax highlighting and indentation features don't seem to be functioning as expected. (I use prettier and eslint in Nx project)

Any idea to fix this ?

You probably need the latest version of Angular Language Service extension for VS Code.

No it is already updated
